# Unable to load huge XML document (incorrectly suppose it's due to the XSLT processing)

Tags: xml

I'm trying to match certain elements using XSLT. My input document is very large and the source XML fails to load after processing the following code (consider especially the first line).

```
    <xsl:template match="XMI/XMI.content/Model_Management.Model/Foundation.Core.Namespace.ownedElement/Model_Management.Package/Foundation.Core.Namespace.ownedElement">
    <rdf:RDF>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="">

            <xsl:for-each select="Foundation.Core.Class">       
                <xsl:for-each select="Foundation.Core.ModelElement.name">
                    <owl:Class rdf:ID="@Foundation.Core.ModelElement.name" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>     

        </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>
</xsl:template>
```

Apparently the XSLT fails to load after "**Model_Management.Model**". The PHP code is as follows:

```
    if ($xml->loadXML($source_xml) == false) {
    die('Failed to load source XML: ' . $http_file);
}
```

It then fails to perform `loadXML` and immediately dies. I think there are two options now.

1) I should set a maximum executing time. Frankly, I don't know how that I do this for the built-in PHP 5 XSLT processor.
2) Think about another way to match.

What would be the best way to deal with this?

The input document can be found at http://krisvandenbergh.be/uml_pricing.xml

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: The input document is over 10000 lines.. It can be found over here http://krisvandenbergh.be/uml_pricing.xml

Comment: And by the way, a dot (".") is a valid character for a qualified name within an XML document, i.e. there is no need for escaping (see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar).

Comment: Changed the questions and gave more detail.

Comment: Btw, the problem is not with your XSLT (which runs fine for me using the .NET XSLT engine) but with loading your input document. It could be that PHP fails because it tries to load a non-existing DTD? Have you tried with the DOCTYPE declaration removed from the input document?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a match on XMI.content, then it is not the "." in Model_Management.Model that is throwing you off.

I seems to me that since you are looking for elements that are 6 layers down, there may be an easier solution.  Have you tried this:

```
<xsl:template match="Foundation.Core.Namespace.ownedElement">
    <!-- other code -->
</xsl:template>
```

The match in the template tag does not have to be that specific usually.  The `select` in your `<xsl:apply-templates>` where you call the template should be as specific as possible.

Comment: Ok, now it does work somehow. However, the xsl returns a lot of strings from other elements I didn't ask for. Should I match all of these elements and output nothing? As in:

<xsl:template match="XMI.header">
<!-- no code here -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Model_Management.Subsystem">
<!-- no code here -->
</xsl:template>

and so on ..